What type of electrical wiring is needed to run power to a15x20 square foot room
I am needing to run enough power to my shed that I'm converting into a small efficiency apartment living space for my brother.  Plus adding an addition for a bathroom that will have a toilet, sink and shower and a tankless water heater for the hot water supply needed for the shed and a couple of receptacles for blow dryer etc. in Bathroom and the shed will have about 10 outlets installed to run Tv, microwave, toaster oven, lamps, laptop and cable box and WiFi router/modem it's about 130 ft from the main panel box inside the home.

Electric or gas tankless? Electric uses a huge amount of power. I believe the US has specific codes on minimum supply to outbuildings; it would be good if you specified where you are.

130 "ft" implies USA location, but please confirm where on the planet you're planning this project. There are some different electrical setups in various places that will define the answers.

In your listing of needed utilities, you need to also account for heating/cooling, which I don't see listed.


small efficiency apartment living space

Before figuring out electric wiring, you need to check with your local zoning and permitting offices. You are, essentially, building an ADU - Accessory Dwelling Unit. There are a lot of issues surrounding this. A shed as a workshop - usually no problem at all. A shed as a workshop that includes plumbing - e.g., for a work sink - there are more rules involved (drain slope in particular can be a complicating factor) but not usually a big deal. But once you start making this into a 24-hour living space, you now have to deal with:

Building code requirements for a kitchen. This may include having certain minimum built-in appliances (they can be plug-in, but not, typically, small countertop appliances) - e.g., at least one cooking method (e.g., at least a 2 burner cooktop or a built-in oven) and a refrigerator/freezer, a sink with hot/cold water, two countertop receptacle circuits (in addition to any circuits required lighting and for permanent cooking appliances), etc.
Building code requirements for a bathroom. Minimum typically toilet, sink, shower or bathtub. At least one dedicated circuit (can only power the bathroom, but can include the lights in the bathroom). Operable window (minimum size requirements apply) or an exhaust fan.
Zoning rules. Varies widely by jurisdiction. Some places you can have one ADU per property, possibly with minimum property size requirements, without any changes at all. Others may require zoning board approval, advance notification to neighbors, etc.
Insulation, roofing materials, minimum inside height - these rules (and probably many others) apply to an ADU but don't apply to a storage shed and may or may not apply to a workshop shed. For example, typical minimum height is 7' for living space. If you have a shed with a sloped roof that is 8' in the middle and 6.5' at the walls then you may have a problem, though possibly fixable by using the areas next to the walls for storage. If most of the ceiling is under 7' then this is pretty much a no-go.
Electric panel location - needs 30" x 36" space in front of it, clear all the time. In a single 15' x 20' that may be hard to do, though the solution is actually pretty easy - mount the panel on the outside of a wall instead of the inside.

And only after you figure out how to make the rest of this work can you figure out the power requirements. The proper way to do that is an NEC Load Calculation, which takes into account the required kitchen and bathroom circuits, general loads (not much for 300 square feet), cooking equipment, water heating, HVAC, etc.
A HUGE factor will be water heating. For a one-person apartment, a small (but not "tiny") electric tank water heater is the way to go. For example, a 38 gallon short tank fits in a roughly 2' wide x 2' deep by 3' high space (some extra may be needed for plumbing, but you don't have to worry about venting with electric) so it can basically be hidden in a corner of the kitchen or bathroom, and provides 51 gallons in the first hour - enough for a nice shower + washing some dishes. That only uses 4500W on a typical 30A circuit.
Compare that to a 13 kW tankless. That will get you a 44 F rise at 2 GPM and a 59 F rise at 1.5 GPM. So it may be enough for one person, depending on how hot and how much water they like in their shower. But it uses 54A and requires a 60A circuit to do that. That is likely to be as much as everything else put together. It could easily push you from a 60A or 70A feed (which you may be able to spare of your 200A typical main panel) to 100A or even more.

Note: it is within the OP's electric utility's rights to require that the ADU have its own electric meter, which also complicates things.

@ThreePhaseEel True. And on the one hand, a separate meter may increase monthly costs, it may also solve two problems - the utility might be able to place it closer to the ADU and if that is a default 200A service then size issues likely go away - though I still don't recommend tankless.
